# I am getting the following error while creating bean in xml **cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean'**

Tags: spring-mvc

I am new to springMVC. Using springMVC 4.2.4, Tomacat 9.0, Maven 4.0,Java 1.8, Eclipse IDE and when I try to write a bean inside a bean, it is showing an error. The following is the configuration xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:resources location="pdfs" mapping="/pdfs/**" />


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springmvc.controller" />

<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean 
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
        p:paramName="language" />
</mvc:interceptors>

<bean

class=
    "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="order" value="1" />
    <property name="ContentNegotiationManager" />
    **<bean** 
    class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean

     class="org.springframework.
     web.accept.PathExtensionContentNegotiationStrategy">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
                        <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <bean

    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView" 
    />
            <bean 
    class="org.springframework.wweb.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean 
    class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
                        <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" 
    />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: can you please share complete error you see

Answer (score 0):

The error is here :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
  xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
```

You didn't include the `bean` namespace. So to solve this, please add it. Here an example (from my project).

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" <!-- THIS ONE-->
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
```

Then to instanciate a new bean :

```
<beans:bean id="...." class="......"/>
```